# Char encoding issue on url, non-english chars -iOS

Tags: ios, url, urlencode, url-encoding, non-english

I am trying to do search on youtube. This code works fine with english chars. But when I try to type non-english letters like ö, ü, ş returns null.

```
NSString *kStrJsonURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=%@&key=API_KEY&format=5&alt=jsonc&callback=?", self.searchField.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStrJsonURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id getJSON) {
        _JSON = getJSON;
        NSLog(@"%@", _JSON);

    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
```

I've tried to encode url like this but doesn't work..

```
[self.searchField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hahve you tried URLEncoding `kStrJsonURL`? See the accepted answer for this post.

[How do I URL encode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this:

```
//Added this line
[self.searchField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
//
    NSString *kStrJsonURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=%@&key=API_KEY&format=5&alt=jsonc&callback=?", self.searchField.text];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kStrJsonURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id getJSON) {
            _JSON = getJSON;
            NSLog(@"%@", _JSON);

    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: I just tried this and checked the failure and I am getting this error: NSDebugDescription = "Unable to convert data to string around character 1.";

Comment: Give this answer a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485868/nsjsonserialization-unable-to-convert-data-to-string