# NSJSONSerialization - Unable to convert data to string on Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a tableView with Json and work perfect, but today we updated our JSon and now don't work. I have this problem:

> Error with Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to
>   convert data to string around character 5060."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around
>   character 5060.}

I found this post and I think work, but is Obj-c [NSJSONSerialization - Unable to convert data to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485868/nsjsonserialization-unable-to-convert-data-to-string)

```
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: rutaJSon)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            self.arrayNombre.removeAll()
            self.arrayTel.removeAll()
            self.arrayMov.removeAll()


            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                //print(json)
```

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: whats the error your getting? what response are you expecting? what response are you actually getting?

Comment: Inspect the JSON response and you'll see that it's exactly what the message is telling you: character 5060 is not valid. Check what happens on your server when encoding the JSON, the issue is there somewhere, not on the client side.

Comment: If your real issue is about encoding: Why did you server changed it? They should put it back to the previous one. If they don't want, you may negociate a parameter in the request to give the wanted encoding. If not, in last call, you can do: NSData to NSString with the encoding from your server response, then, that NSString to NSData with the 8TF8 encoding, then you can use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your server is not using one of the correct JSON encoding types. From the docs:

> *The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.*

Your server needs to encode the data properly.